# Filter based on two databases

Tags: sql-server

I have the same query on two databases, but in the first database it finds me data, while in the second one it does not. Is it possible to build on these two bases so that I can filter all those that exist in the first base and not the second. These are my sql query:

```
use firstDB;
SELECT A_ANSPRECHPARTNER.AAS_ID FROM A_ANSPRECHPARTNER LEFT OUTER JOIN A_ADRESSEN ON A_ANSPRECHPARTNER.AAS_ADR_ID = A_ADRESSEN.ADR_ID  WHERE ADR_Nr = 106740

use secondDB;
SELECT A_ANSPRECHPARTNER.AAS_ID FROM A_ANSPRECHPARTNER LEFT OUTER JOIN A_ADRESSEN ON A_ANSPRECHPARTNER.AAS_ADR_ID = A_ADRESSEN.ADR_ID WHERE ADR_Nr = 106740
```

the current result

[image]

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih this is just one example based on ADR_Nr where data exists and where it does not exist, I would like as a desired result to get all ADR_Nr existing in the first database while not existing in the second database.

Comment: @D-Shih is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If these databases are on the same server you can put each of your queries in a subquery specifying the database name when referencing the table. Then left join the subquery on firstDB to the subquery on secondDB filtering the records where there is a record in firstDB, but not in secondDB.

```
SELECT    DB_1.*
FROM      (
              SELECT          A_ANSPRECHPARTNER.AAS_ID
              FROM            firstDB.dbo.A_ANSPRECHPARTNER
              LEFT OUTER JOIN firstDB.dbo.A_ADRESSEN ON A_ANSPRECHPARTNER.AAS_ADR_ID = A_ADRESSEN.ADR_ID
          ) DB_1
LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT          A_ANSPRECHPARTNER.AAS_ID
              FROM            secondDB.dbo.A_ANSPRECHPARTNER
              LEFT OUTER JOIN secondDB.dbo.A_ADRESSEN ON A_ANSPRECHPARTNER.AAS_ADR_ID = A_ADRESSEN.ADR_ID
          ) DB_2 ON DB_1.ADR_Nr = DB_2.ADR_Nr
WHERE     DB_2.ADR_Nr IS NULL
  AND     DB_1.ADR_Nr = 106740
```

You can just remove the `AND DB_1.ADR_Nr = 106740` in order to find all records in firstDB that are not in secondDB. If these databases are on different servers you would have to set up a linked server and add that to the beginning of your table reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this is already yielding some results, I just need a list of all for example from DB_1 ADR_NR which <> 0 and while DB_2 ADR_Nr== 0

Comment: some like   WHERE DB_2.ADR_Nr IS NULL
 AND DB_1.ADR_Nr IS NOT NULL ist that possible?

Comment: That is what the above query is doing. A LEFT JOIN is all the records from the table/query on the left side of the join and only the records that match the join criteria from the table/query on the right side of the join. So by definition, the way the query is written in my answer DB_1.ADR_Nr will not be NULL. And by adding the where clause of `DB_2.ADR_Nr IS NULL` takes care of that requirement.